# My pattern is wrong, how do I make it DRY?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, oop, optimization, dry

So I got this TitleWindow based Flex application where these windows are called by static functions written in them.
This is how it looks like when an entity needs do be created or edited from a DataGrid:

```
private function incluir():void {
    NavioForm.incluir(dg.dataProvider);
}

private function atualizar():void {
    NavioForm.atualizar(dg.dataProvider, dg.selectedIndex);
}
```

It's working perfectly from this side.

But since I used static functions, the code is starting to get a bit repetitive, as we can see on the examples below:

[Script tag of a CRUD form(incluir == include, atualizar == update, excluir == delete)]

```
...

[Bindable] private var navio:Navio;

public static function incluir(dataList:IList):void {
    var form:NavioForm = new NavioForm();
    form.action = FormWindow.ACTION_NEW + Navio.name;

    form.navio = new Navio();
    form.navio.lastUpdate = new Date();

    form.result = function():void {
        PortoService.obj.persistirNavio(form.navio).result(function(navio:Navio):void {
            dataList.addItem(navio);
            form.close();
        }).fault(function(event:FaultEvent):void {
            if(event.fault.faultString == 'duplicate key') {
                Util.showError("This vessel's IMO is already present in our database.");
            } else throw event.fault;
        });
    };

    PopUp.add(form);
}

public static function atualizar(dataList:IList, index:int):void {
    var form:NavioForm = new NavioForm();
    form.action = FormWindow.ACTION_UPDATE + Navio.name;
    form.imoRecieved = true;

    form.navio = dataList[index];

    PortoService.obj.obter(Navio, form.navio.key).result(function(navio:Navio):void {
        form.navio = navio;
        form.navio.lastUpdate = new Date();
    });

    form.result = function():void {
        PortoService.obj.persistir(form.navio).result(function(navio:Navio):void {
            dataList[index] = navio;
            form.close();
        }).fault(function(event:FaultEvent):void {
            if(event.fault.faultString == 'duplicate key') {
                Util.showError("This vessel's IMO is already present in our database.");
            } else throw event.fault;
        });
    };

    PopUp.add(form);
}

...
```

Script tag of another CRUD form:

```
...
[Bindable] private var vesselType:VesselType;

public static function incluir(dataList:IList):void {
    var form:VesselTypeForm = new VesselTypeForm();
    form.action = FormWindow.ACTION_NEW + VesselType.name;

    form.vesselType = new VesselType();

    form.result = function():void {
        CoreService.obj.persistir(form.vesselType).result(function(type:VesselType):void {
            dataList.addItem(type);
            form.close();
        });
    };

    PopUp.add(form);
}

public static function atualizar(dataList:IList, index:int):void {
    var form:VesselTypeForm = new VesselTypeForm();
    form.action = FormWindow.ACTION_UPDATE + VesselType.name;

    form.vesselType = Util.clone(dataList[index]);

    form.result = function():void {
        CoreService.obj.persistir(form.vesselType).result(function(type:VesselType):void {
            dataList[index] = type;
            form.close();
        });
    };
    form.deleteClick = function():void {
        CoreService.obj.excluir(form.vesselType.key).result(function():void {
            dataList.removeItemAt(index);
            form.close();
        });
    };

    PopUp.add(form);
}
```

So, is there a design pattern or any other technique to make this work?

Comment: Is it a requirement that the forms be static?

Comment: No, It's not. It was my first mistake, I thought it would be a good idea.

Comment: Seems like you could have a 'form' base class with 'incluir', etc functions. Then have subclasses that build from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a crud component that you instantiate with all of the dynamic stuff such as the data provider location and it broadcasts events (or signals) that you assign appropriate listeners to.